# Python Selenium: How to return a list of all XPaths for a given URL

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am looking for a way to gather a list of all XPaths for a given webpage. For instance, if I was to do:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = [MY PATH HERE])
driver.get("https://www.google.com)
x = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html')
```

It seems that `x` should contain everything on the page, but I am unsure if it would collect their XPaths and, if so, I am unsure of how to access them. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: all the xpaths would be the html...

Comment: I'm looking for a way to have all possible XPaths in detail - something that might look like ```[ '/html/div/div[10]/a', '/html/div[2]/div/a', '/html/body/div/div[10]/', ... ]``` if that makes sense.

Comment: There's an infinite number of XPaths possible - even if you exclude the ones that don't select anything. I guess you probably want one XPath for each element in the page, or perhaps for each node in the page. Or perhaps you only want those that are structurally distinct, e.g. /A/B/C/D is one XPath even though it selects multiple elements. Whatever it is you want, you need to explain it better.

Comment: I am looking for one for each node in the page. Sorry about the lack of specificity, I am still new to web scraping and XPaths in general.